# UIView gradient background is not getting set

Tags: ios, swift3, gradient

I have a `UIViewController` that is also a `UIScrollViewDelegate`
The `UIViewController` has multiple slides that are `UIViews` and for each slide I want to set a different gradient background color programmatically, however it does not seem to be working as no gradient is being set.

My `UIView` extension

```
import UIKit
extension UIView {
    func addGradient(){
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.black, UIColor.orange]
        let backgroundIndex:UInt32 = 0;
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: backgroundIndex)
    }
}
```

My `FirstSlide` that has it's own `FirstSlide.xib`

```
import UIKit

class FirstSlide: UIView {

}
```

In my `WelcomeSliderViewController`

```
import UIKit

class WelcomeSliderViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var slideScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pagerControl: UIPageControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slideScrollView.delegate = self
        let slides = createSlides()
        setupSliderView(slides: slides)
        pagerControl.numberOfPages = slides.count
        pagerControl.currentPage = 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



    @IBAction func pagerControlClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        self.slideScrollView
            .scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(
                x: Int(self.slideScrollView.frame.size.width) * self.pagerControl.currentPage,
                y: 0,
                width:Int(self.slideScrollView.frame.size.width),
                height: Int(self.slideScrollView.frame.size.height)),
                                 animated: true)
    }


    func createSlides() -> [UIView] {
        let firstSlide: FirstSlide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FirstSlide", owner:self , options: nil)?.first as! FirstSlide
 let secondSlide: SecondSlide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SecondSlide", owner:self , options: nil)?.first as! SecondSlide

        firstSlide.addGradient()


return [firstSlide, SecondSlide]

    }

    func setupSliderView(slides:[UIView]) {
        slideScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        slideScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)

        for i in 0 ..< slides.count{
            slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            slideScrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
        }

    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView : UIScrollView){
        let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / view.frame.width)
        pagerControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you are passing UIColors instead of CGColors in the .colors Array of the CAGradientLayer.

It should be like this:

```
   func addGradient(){
    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.orange.cgColor]
    let backgroundIndex:UInt32 = 0;
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: backgroundIndex)
}
```

Comment: how would I go about setting the gradient in the `FirstSlide` class?

Comment: You just need to override awakeFromNib function in your UIView Subclass and call addGradient() like this:                                                           override func awakeFromNib() {
        addGradient()
    }

Comment: Any idea why the gradient is not applied to full screen on the iphone 6 plus and iphone 7 plus

Comment: The gradient will be added to a UIVIew, so it depends on the size of it. If it is working on other devices sizes it may be because your UIView needs to be resized depending on your device. This can be done with Autolayout.